# Powershell script to pull info from file name from list of folders

Tags: powershell

I have a list of files in a folder each are in this format: custID_invID_prodID. For every file I need to break it into sections based on '_'. Currently I have this code

```
$files = Get-ChildItem test *.txt
$Part = $files.Split(';')[$($files.Split('_').Count-1)]
Write-Host  "${Part}"
```

The problem is that it appears that `$files` is a list of all the files and I need it to run each file on its own. Can anyone offer some pointers on how to do this for the entire folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"The problem is that it appears that $files is a list of all the files and I need it to run each file on its own."

That is correct, running get-childitem on a folder will give you a list of all files (and subfolders). In order to go through them one by one, you need a loop:

```
$file = @()
$files = Get-ChildItem Test *.txt 
foreach($f in $files)
{
    $file += ([String]$f).Split("_")
    $count = ([String]$f).Split("_") | Measure-Object | select count
}
if($count.count -eq 3) {
    for($i=2; $i -lt $file.length; $i+=3) {
        $file[$i] = $file[$i].trimend(".txt")
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you sir!! Quick question, if a file was missing one of the parts is it possible to create a check and have it skip that file if any part is missing? I am thinking count how many times '_' is found in the name?

Comment: Sorry! Spoke too soon, I have done this by using: (Select-String -Pattern ([regex]'_+') -InputObject $Subject -AllMatches).Matches.Count

Comment: Well, I'm glad your trying and learning! ... I did it by measure object, and made the scenario for when there are three ID's.. so implementing 2 and 1 shouldn't be hard... Also was able to use the split command with a cast first... forgot about that, updated my post

Comment: Hey! Your code had some issues running with my script but I fixed it by moving just the for loop into the foreach loop and changing i=2 to i=3.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: @aDroidman are you sure it doesn't work? I tested it with ten files... doesn't make sense to have the for in the foreach cuz you'd be doing tons of `trimend(".txt")` that wouldn't actually have an effect... but note the count will always just get the last file's count, and the script assumes all the files would have the same naming convention

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this by using this code:

```
$Part = $file.name.Split('_')[$($file.name.Split('_').Count-1)]
Write-Host "${Part}"
```